# What's the best UI framework to annotate data points / data series?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, charts, highcharts

Recently I got a requirement where

I have a certain amount of time series data, I need to show the data on a chart on a web page.
(I know this can be done easily since there is **Highcharts**, **Google charts**, etc)

However, a more complicated feature request came up. **I need to be able to annotate one or more data points on the chart, and annotate them as - say Test Run 1, and maybe another series of data points at Test Run 2**. (You can think of it as maybe someone is playing around with a hardware, the first time he collected a set of data, and the second time he collected another a set of data. I want to be able to annotate and diffenrentiate those data sets on the chart)

I will need to preserve those segmentations/groupings and save them in a persistent store, so that next time I load the chart, I can show those grouping again on the chart.

Does anyone know what is the best way to do this? Or are there existing features of any Javascript UI framework that's already capable of doing it?

Thanks so much.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/twelve-javascript-libraries-data-visualization/

Comment: `D3.js` might be useful